# Intersect dictionaries with keys averaged

Tags: python, dictionary, intersect

If i have this dictionary:

`a = {'alpha':12,'beta':13,'gamma':14}`

and this one:

`b = {'andora':19,'beta:14','gamma':19}`

and this one:

`c = {'beta':11,'gamma':20}`

how do i intersect the keys such that the resultant dictionary would have values as the average of the values in the given dictionaries.

for example:

`intersect([a,b,c]) -> {'beta':12.6666666667,'gamma':17.6666666667}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def intersect(dicts):
    common_keys = reduce(set.intersection, map(set, dicts))
    num = float(len(dicts))
    return {k: sum(d[k] for d in dicts)/num for k in common_keys}
```

Example:

```
>>> a = {'alpha':12,'beta':13,'gamma':14}
>>> b = {'andora':19,'beta':14,'gamma':19}
>>> c = {'beta':11,'gamma':20}
>>> intersect([a, b, c])
{'beta': 12.666666666666666, 'gamma': 17.666666666666668}
```

If you want to be able to call it like `intersect(a, b, c)` instead of needing to wrap them in a list, just change the `def` line to `def intersect(*dicts)` (the body can stay exactly the same).

Comment: is dicts (the argument) a list of dicts?

Comment: Yes it is, I used the same example from your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
>>> keys = a.viewkeys() & b.viewkeys() & c.viewkeys()
>>> keys
set(['beta', 'gamma'])
>>> {k: (a[k]+b[k]+c[k])/3.0  for k in keys}
{'beta': 12.666666666666666, 'gamma': 17.666666666666668}
```

Function:

```
>>> def get_keys(*args):
...     return reduce(set.intersection,map(set,args))
... 
>>> get_keys(a,b,c)
set(['beta', 'gamma'])
```

`intersect` function:

```
def intersect(dics):
    keys = reduce(set.intersection,map(set,dics))
    return {k: sum(x[k] for x in dics)/float(len(dics))  for k in keys}
... 
>>> intersect([a,b,c])
{'beta': 12.666666666666666, 'gamma': 17.666666666666668}
```

Comment: in this case you know that there are 3 dicts rite? how to do this if you dont know how many dicts are there, that's why i have defined intersect as a function which takes a list of dicts @Ashwini Chaudhary

Comment: @tenstar I've added a function for that.

Comment: Chaudary can you please provide a function `intersect()` which takes an indefinite number of args and returns what i asked for?

Comment: @tenstar see my updated solution. Next time specify your requirements in the question body itself, don't post them in pieces.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from operator import and_
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> def intersect(*dicts):
    return dict((key,sum(D[key] for D in dicts)/len(dicts)) for key in reduce(and_,map(set,dicts)))

>>> intersect(a,b,c)
{'beta': 12.666666666666666, 'gamma': 17.666666666666668}
```

#### Tiny explanation:

`and_` is just operator which do the following `and_(a,b) === a and b`.

`reduce` just apply `and` to all the members, so `reduce(and_,map(set,dicts)) === a and b and c`, which produces intersection of dictionary keys.

```
>>> reduce(and_,map(set,dicts))
set(['beta', 'gamma'])
```

Then we just pass through all those keys and calculate sum of the values from all the dicts corresponding to that key `sum(D[key] for D in dicts)`, and divide it by the number of dicts, so we get average for that key, and then get it packed into resultant dictionary via generator expression.

P.S. I wouldn't call this function `intersect`. Something like `common_key_average` would do better.